# Install Unity8 apps on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-core, unity8

Is there a way to install Unity8 apps like terminal and file explorer as snappy packages on Ubuntu 16.04LTS?
I am not looking for a PPA with precompiled binaries, but for the actual snappy packages. Is it possible or should we wait for a next release?

Answer (score 1):

Most of those apps are not yet available as snaps ([with the exception of the clock and calculator](https://uappexplorer.com/apps?q=author%3AUbuntu%20Core%20App%20Developers&type=snappy) which can be installed by the names `ubuntu-clock-app`and `ubuntu-calculator-app`).
You can track the status of the snap packages in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-filemanager-app/+bug/1552100).